# no sound card detected in ASUS E200HA

Tags: 14.04, drivers, asus, soundcard, mint

No soud card is detected when I install Ubuntu 14.04 and linux mint 17.3 in my asus E200HA.

**The driver for windows directly from the suport of asus says:
conexant Audio driver version V1.62.0.58**

running lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2280] (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b0] (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22dc] (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b5] (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2298] (rev 22)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22c8] (rev 22)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:229c] (rev 22)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
```

and running
 cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---

please help thanks

KERNEL version uname -a:

Linux galva-E200HA 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I change the kernel to 4.4 but still not working

Still not working :

```
$ uname -a
Linux galva-E200HA 4.4.0-13-generic #29~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 20:25:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

STeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b0 (rev 22) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 117
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 118
    Memory at 91639000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 22) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 116
    Memory at 91600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 119
    Memory at 91500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 91400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 22) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 91200000-913fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2b31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 314
    Memory at 91200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
```

Comment: What is the kernel version? `uname -a`

Comment: The answer for uaname.-a:Linux galva-E200HA 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try to upgrade kernel to 4.4 by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial`.

Comment: I created a bug report on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1563110